# i have trouble in combobox datasource

Tags: c#

I have 1 combobox that have datasource (database), I use LINQ.
this in my code:

```
private void Return_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        button1.Enabled = false;
        var buka = (from db in Program.data.Transactions where db.ReturnDate == null select db);
        comboBox1.DataSource = buka;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;


    } // my form load
```

and this is my combobox selected index :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            var open = (from db in Program.data.Transactions where db.TransactionID == comboBox1.Text select db).FirstOrDefault();

            label10.Text = open.StaffID;
            label11.Text = open.ClientName;
            label12.Text = open.CarID;
            label13.Text = open.StartDate.ToString();
            label14.Text = open.EndDate.ToString();
            label15.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy");

            var car = (from db in Program.data.MsCars where db.CarID == label12.Text select db).FirstOrDefault();
            int rentduration;
            int lateduration;
            double extrachange;
            double totalprice;
            string a = car.Price.ToString();
            rentduration = open.EndDate.Value.DayOfYear - open.StartDate.Value.DayOfYear;
            lateduration = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear - open.EndDate.Value.DayOfYear;

            totalprice = rentduration * double.Parse(a);

            label17.Text = totalprice.ToString();
        }
```

My problem is how to add combobox datasource from database? considering combobox use an array.

Comment: `var buka = (...).ToList();`

Comment: `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "PropertyName";`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, but if your combobox is showing `Program.data.Transactions` in the combobox for every result in the LINQ query (as assumed by the `Return_Load` method), you need to look into the `DisplayMember` property for the value you wish to present to your user (on display) and `ValueMember` for the values you wish to work with, such as the `TransactionID`.

You also may need to call the ToList() function to enumerate the records -

```
var buka = (from db in Program.data.Transactions where db.ReturnDate == null select db).ToList();
```

Once you've got the ValueMember setup, you would then substitute `combobox1.Text` for `combobox1.SelectedValue` (casting to the relevant data type accordingly)

Setting the DisplayMember and the ValueMember of combobox1 to 'TransactionID' (so as to display and use the same value), then in your SelectedIndexChanged Handler, you could use:

```
var open = (from db in Program.data.Transactions where db.TransactionID == (object_type)comboBox1.SelectedValue select db).FirstOrDefault();
```

...making sure to replace `object_type` with the actual type, be it string, int or whatever.

... and ...

```
var car = (from db in Program.data.MsCars where db.CarID == open.CarID select db).FirstOrDefault();
```

Be sure to test for NullReferenceExceptions and handle what happens if the records don't exist gracefully.

Comment: Suggested Reading on Data Binding: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html

Comment: i got it,  but when i load the form and before i change the combobox index, all my label are change to the value of the database